# Purchase digital content with Crypto Currency in iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect, itunes-store, cryptocurrency

In one of our application, we are going to introduce digital content purchase mechanism with crypto currency. So here are my doubts:

1) Is it durable and achievable?

2) If yes, is Apple going to allow this kind of implementation and accept it to iTunes?.

Comment: The answer to 2 is no, so the answer to 1 doesn't matter. You must use In-App purchase

Answer (score 4):

The criteria is 'if goods cannot be used in the app'.  Only then you can use a system other than IAP (including a system like Crypto Currency)

Digital Goods which are ment to be used within the App must be purchased trough In-App Purchase. If you use any other mechanism, then your app will be rejected.

**From the [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase)**

> If you want to unlock features or functionality within your app, (by
>   way of example: subscriptions, in-game currencies, game levels, access
>   to premium content, or unlocking a full version), you must use in-app
>   purchase. Apps may not use their own mechanisms to unlock content or
>   functionality, such as license keys, augmented reality markers, QR
>   codes, etc. Apps and their metadata may not include buttons, external
>   links, or other calls to action that direct customers to purchasing
>   mechanisms other than in-app purchase

Someone has asked similar question on Apple Thread also. have a look at the following [thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/106792)

Comment: Correct answer. All purchases for digital goods and services must go through the in-app purchases API.

Answer (score 0):

Answer on the second question: if you want to implement some kind of purchases in your app you also should follow items from the review guidelines:

**From the [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):**

> **3.1.5 (a) Goods and Services Outside of the App:** If your app enables people to purchase goods or services that will be consumed outside of the app, you must use purchase methods other than in-app purchase to collect those payments, such as Apple Pay or traditional credit card entry.
>
> **3.1.5 (b) Cryptocurrencies**:
>
> ---
>
> 4. Initial Coin Offerings: Apps facilitating Initial Coin Offerings (“ICOs”), cryptocurrency futures trading, and other crypto-securities or quasi-securities trading must come from established banks, securities firms, futures commission merchants (“FCM”), or other approved financial institutions and must comply with all applicable law.